# if element has opacity=1 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement, toggle

I have a piece of code that's not working and I just can't figure out why.
Here's the simplified code:

HTML:

```
<div id="objInfo">
    <div id="button"></div>
    <img src="img/x.png" class="obj_x">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#objInfo { opacity: 0; display: none }
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
if ($('#objInfo').css('opacity') != "1")
{
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#objInfo").css("display", "block");
        $("#objInfo").animate({opacity: 1, top: "-25px"});
    });
}
else
{
     $(".obj_x").click(function(){
        $("#objInfo").css("display", "none");
        $("#objInfo").animate({opacity: 0, top: "+25px"});
    });

}
```

So basically, I wanna have a popup (#objInfo) that appears when #button is clicked and disappears when .obj_x is clicked. And also, I want #objInfo to disappear when I click outside of it. (I haven't added that to the code, because there's no need to. Once the if statement works that'll be the least problem to be solved. And that's why I need that statement) 
The if statement is just there to check whether the box is displayed or not, and when it IS, I want to be able to toggle it back off using either the dedicated obj_x button or the click outside the box.

I hope I explained it well enough for you guys. This is my first post, so please be gentle... ;)
Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you want something like this??? http://jsfiddle.net/1torpj4j/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wanna have a popup (#objInfo) that appears when #button is clicked and disappears when .obj_x is clicked

The following code should work:

HTML

```
<div id="objInfo">
  <div class="obj_x">BLABLA</div>
</div>

<button id="show">Show</button>
```

CSS

```
#objInfo { display: none }
```

JS

```
function hideBlock(){

    $("#objInfo").css('display','none')
    $("#show").css('display','inline-block')

    $(document).mousedown(function(){ return false;})
}

function displayBlock(){

    $("#objInfo").css('display','block')
    $("#show").css('display','none')

    $(document).mousedown( hideBlock )
}


$("#show").click( displayBlock )
$(".obj_x").click( hideBlock )
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rpdmwqo8/1/

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! Didnt think about just putting it in functions. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for

HTML

```
<button type="submit" id="btn">PopUp</button>
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="popUp">
    <p>
        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    </p>
    <span class="popUp-close" title="Close"></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.overlay {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 6;
}
.popUp {
    background: #e9f1f4;
    border: 1px solid #e1e2e4;
    display: none;
    left: 50%;
    width: 550px;
    padding: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 7;
}
.popUp-close {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: -13px;
    right: -13px;
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    /*background: url("../images/close-btn.png") no-repeat;*/
    background: #ccc;
}
```

JavaScript

```
//PopUp Script Starts
function pop(action) {

    if (action === 'reset') {
        // Reset popup code.
        var $width = $('.popUp').outerWidth(),
            $height = $('.popUp').outerHeight();

        $('.popUp').css({
            'margin-top': -$height / 2,
            'margin-left': -$width / 2
        });
    }
    if (action === 'show') {
        // Open popup code.
        //$('.wrapper').append('<div class="overlay white"></div><div class="popUp"><div></div><span class="popup-close"></span></div>');
        pop('reset');
        $('.overlay, .popUp').fadeIn(500);
    }

    if (action === 'hide') {
        // Close popup code.
        $('.overlay, .popUp').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    }
};

var keyDown; // on escape
window.onkeydown = function() {
    keyDown = true;
};

window.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27 && keyDown) {
        pop('hide');
        keyDown = false;
    }
};

$(document).on('click', '.popUp-close, .overlay', function() {
    pop('hide');
});
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function() {
    pop('show');
});
//PopUp Script Ends
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bogd4px8/

Comment: Thanks man! Bit of a complicated way tho - but it still worked ;) Thanks for the time.